# How to access `request_seen()` inside Spider?

Tags: scrapy

I have a Spider and I have a situation where I want to check if the request I am going to schedule already exists in [`request_seen()`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/dupefilters.py) or not?

I don't want any method to check inside a download/spider middleware, I just want to check inside my Spider.

Is there any way to call that method?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the dupe filter itself from the spider like this:

```py
self.dupefilter = self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df
```

then you could use that in other places to check:

```py
req = scrapy.Request('whatever')
if self.dupefilter.request_seen(req):
    # it's already been seen
    pass
else:
    # never saw this one coming
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to yours with pipeline. Following command is the code that I use.

You should specify an identifier and then go with it to check whether it is seen or not.

```
class SeenPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.isbns_seen = set()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['isbn'] in self.isbns_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found : %s" %item)
        else:
            self.isbns_seen.add(item['isbn'])
            return item
```

Note: You can use these codes within your spider, too

Comment: Thats the manual method, I want to access the scrapy's default `request_seen() ` method inside Spider